# To show a power series is a Taylor series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to prove

> if $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(x - a)^n$ then the series is the Taylor series of $f$

without using complex analysis, as done [here](http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math39/lectures/lecture-42.pdf)?

Comment: You can show that you may differentiate a convergent power series term-by-term. Then it's clear that $f^{(n)}(a) = n!a_n$.

Comment: You need to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n k a_k (x-a)^{k-1}$ converges uniformly in the set where $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k (x-a)^k$ converges absolutely. Then you can use the result of advanced calculus that lets you differentiate term by term. How can you show that the derivative sum converges uniformly?

Comment: @Ian The convergence is usually only _locally_ uniform. Of course that's sufficient.

Comment: Ah, right, yes. Uniform on compact subsets of the (open) set where the sum converges absolutely.